# Codepush - Updating the app from store issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm using codepush on a cordova application, And I published a codepush version for v0.6.0.

I had add extra SDK's and uploaded new binaries to app store, When the user downloads the update from the appstore the codepush plugin still points the user to the old version location.

Is there a way that when the app is update from the store it will be used as the latest version? (In the case that codepush doesnt know a newer version).

I want to avoid the situation which will cause my users to download 2 updates, one from the store and than again from codepush.

Answer (score 2):

CodePush allows you to release new versions targeting specific binary (store) versions using the `--targetBinaryVersion` flag.

You could:

- release a code-push version targeting 1.1.* binaries
- release a new 1.2 binary version using the up-to-date JS bundle

In this way, any old user with 1.1 will get the OTA update, but if someone downloads a fresh 1.2 version from the store, code-push won't try to update the bundle.

Link to the docs explaining how to target specific binary version for the `release` cli command:
https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/tree/master/cli#target-binary-version-parameter